# How to convert base R syntax into dplyr/tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to convert this conditional subset statement using bracket indexing in base R into something that uses dplyr syntax.

`newdat = dat[ps >= min(ps[dat$treat == 1]) & ps <= max(ps[dat$treat == 0]), ]`

I tried the following:

`newdat = dat %>% filter(ifelse(treat == 1, ps >= min(ps), ps <= max(ps)))`

But it did not return a subset.

Comment: `newdat <- dat %>%
  filter(ps >= min(ps[treat == 1]), ps <= max(ps[treat == 0]))`

Comment: Thanks, interesting that the brackets still have to be used.

Comment: @R_studio_user11 ps seems to be a vector, so what were you expecting?

Comment: @Mark I thought that when using tidyverse notation there's no use of brackets or dollar signs or notation from base R

Comment: I understand why you'd have that impression but I think tidyverse still uses single brackets for things

Comment: You'll use brackets and dollars with the tidyverse too, it's just that with data frames the tidyverse vision is that columns should be seen as variables in the scope of the data.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** We can use filter/between:

```
# test data
dat <- data.frame(ps = seq(-1.1, 1.1, .2), treat = rep(0:1, 6))

# soln from question
ps <- dat$ps  # need this for soln in question to make sense
newdat = dat[ps >= min(ps[dat$treat == 1]) & ps <= max(ps[dat$treat == 0]), ]
rownames(newdat) <- NULL # need this to make solutions identical

# tidyverse
library(dplyr)
newdat2 <- dat %>%
  filter(between(ps, min(ps[treat == 1]), max(ps[treat == 0])))

# compare
identical(newdat, newdat2)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2)** Here is a variation on that which is longer code-wise:

```
newdat3 <- dat %>%
  filter(between(ps,
    filter(., treat == 1) %>% slice_min(ps) %>% pull(ps),
    filter(., treat == 0) %>% slice_max(ps) %>% pull(ps)
  )
)

# compare
identical(newdat, newdat3)
## [1] TRUE
```